# What is the way 召されなば is conjugated?

Tags: conjugations, keigo, classical-japanese

In a bit old Japanese, the phrase:

> 草鞋{わらじ}を召{め}されなば

means "if you (talking to a superior) put on the straw sandals" (I assume from the context).

Where does the conjugation ～なば of 召される come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 草鞋を召され**なば**

召されなば＝召す＋される[敬語]＋な[完了の助動詞]＋[ば](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/172830/meaning/m1u/%E3%81%B0/)[条件の接続助詞]

This な should be 未然形 of ぬ.

[なば](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/164643/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%B0/) is treated as a compound word in the linked dictionary page, and means "having done (something) ~".

I'm no good at old Japanese, but I think it says that when (someone) has put on (grass/straw) sandals, in polite language.